# Derive the Quadratic Equation

Tags: polynomials, quadratic-forms

Find the Quadratic Equation whose roots are $2+\sqrt3$ and $2-\sqrt3$.

Some basics:

> - The general form of a Quadratic Equation is $ax^2+bx+c=0$
> - In Quadratic Equation, $ax^2+bx+c=0$, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of the given Quadratic Equation, Then,
>   $$\alpha+\beta=\frac{-b}{a}, \alpha\beta=\frac{c}{a}$$

I am here confused that how we can derive a Quadratic Equations from the given roots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here $$-\frac ba=\alpha+\beta=2+\sqrt3+2-\sqrt3=4$$ and
$$\frac ca=\alpha\beta=(2+\sqrt3)(2-\sqrt3)=2^2-3=1$$

So, the quadratic equation becomes $$x^2-4x+1=0$$

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the sum and product relations for roots is much more *specialized knowledge* than is needed for this problem, although perhaps the problem was intended to be an application of these relations.

Just work backwards from "the solution":

$$x = 2 \pm \sqrt{3} \; \implies \; (x-2)=\pm\sqrt{3} \; \implies \; (x-2)^2 = \left(\pm \sqrt{3}\right)^2$$

$$\implies \; (x-2)^2 = 3,$$

and now you have a quadratic equation whose solution is $x = 2 \pm \sqrt{3}.$

Answer (score 1):

$$
0 = \left(x-\alpha\right)\left(x-\beta\right)=x^2 -\left(\alpha+\beta\right)x + \alpha \beta
$$

Answer (score 0):

Well if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of a quadratic equation

We can write the general quadratic equation which have roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as follows

$k(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)=0$ where k is a real number

This can be expanded out to be the following.

$k[x^2-(\alpha+\beta)x+\alpha\beta]=0$

In your case let $\alpha=2+\sqrt3$ and $\beta=2-\sqrt3$

$\alpha+\beta=2+\sqrt3 +2-\sqrt3=4$

$\alpha\beta= (2+\sqrt3)(2-\sqrt3)=2^2-\sqrt3^2=4-3=1$

So the relavent quadratic equations are,

$k(x^2-4x+1)=0$

Normally if we are told to find "the quadratic equation" we take k to be 1.

Then we get,

$x^2-4x+1=0$

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a standard question from the R.D. Sharma textbook used in Indian schools. A common trick I use for this type of sums is

$$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$

Comparing with the given roots, we get

$$x = \frac{4 \pm \sqrt{4 - 4c}}{2}$$

In this step we find the value of $a$ to be $1$, $b$ to be $-4$.

To find $c$, simply multiply the roots and divide by $a$ to get c.

$$c = \frac{(2 + \sqrt 3)(2 - \sqrt 3)}{1}$$

$$ c = \frac{4 - 3}{1}$$

$$c = 1$$

We know that the standard form of a quadratic equation is

$$ax^2 + bx + c = 0$$

Hence substituting $a$, $b$ and $c$ into the standard form yields

$$x^2 - 4x + 1 = 0$$